# What Command Line tools to connect from Unix to remote Windows?

Tags: ssh, command-line, scripting, ansible

I need to make some scripts for connecting from a Unix server to several Windows stations for automating file transfers. GUI is not needed and I can't install any additional software into Windows boxes also. Which RDP clients support scripting or are there any separate utilities to look for?

Comment: Is powershell remoting an option?

Comment: Unfortunately powershell is not an option for me

Answer (score 3):

As for software for doing remote Windows automation tasks from the Unix/Linux side, I am aware of:

- [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) - devops automation framework
- [Rundeck](http://www.techpaste.com/2015/08/rundeck-windows-nodes-configuration/) - web based Java automation framework
- [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) - pscp tools, for talking SSH on the Windows remote side
- [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) - cross-compiled GNU tools framework for Windows
- [Win32-openSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH) - Microsoft´s port of OpenSSH
- [freeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com) - a free SSH implementation for Windows

As for the requirement about not installing software:

- cygwin disqualifies as you need to install the whole stack;
- rundeck needs in the Windows side, modules/agents for basic commands, and to support scripts, SSH;

[Rundeck Windows Nodes Configuration](http://www.techpaste.com/2015/08/rundeck-windows-nodes-configuration/)

- Ansible boasts about not needing to install anything both in Windows and Linux nodes;

[Ansible:Windows support](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html)

> Starting in version 1.7, Ansible also contains support for managing
>   Windows machines. This uses native PowerShell remoting, rather than
>   SSH. Ansible will still be run from a Linux control machine, and uses
>   the “winrm” Python module to talk to remote hosts. No additional
>   software needs to be installed on the remote machines for Ansible to
>   manage them, it still maintains the agentless properties that make it
>   popular on Linux/Unix.

- Openssh do needs to be installed, please keep reading on.
- FreeSSHd also needs to be installed. We have been using it for years, works quite well, however I do believe Win32-openSSH is the "official" solution. Just mentioning it both as an alternative, and because I have not actually used Win32-openSSH yet.

So I do recommend investigating Ansible, and/or running small Windows/DOS batch commands over SSH/Win32-openSSH for more simple tasks.

We have installed here SSH daemons in the Windows servers a few years ago, and they can come very handy for small housekeeping tasks. It is so much more convenient entering an SSH session, than having to invoke a vmware console.